# Getting particular substring using xslt1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a string as below.

```
<freeForm>
   <text>mnr.getValue().put("xyz","pqr");</text>
</freeForm>
```

From the above xml portion i need to get the string **xyz**.

Please provide pointers to achieve the same using xslt1.0.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this XPath expression**:

```
substring-before(
     substring-after(/*/*, &apos;"&apos;),
     &apos;"&apos;
                 )
```

**Here is a short, complete XSLT transformation that evaluates this XPath expression and outputs the result of evaluating it**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   'substring-before(
         substring-after(/*/*, &apos;"&apos;),
         &apos;"&apos;
                     )'/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<freeForm>
   <text>mnr.getValue().put("xyz","pqr");</text>
</freeForm>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
xyz
```